# Return an array of values as a result

Tags: mongodb

I am querying a MongoDB database from a shell, I have a query that returns documents:

```
{"events" : "A"}
{"events" : "B"}
{"events" : "C"}
{"events" : "C"}
```

I would like to format the return to just return the values like so:

```
{"events" : [A, B, C, C]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-aggregation) can be used to get your expected result.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : null,
           events: { $push: "$events" }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I just couldn't figure out how to group duplicate values.